# Dismiss alertDialog from other function

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

How can I dismiss an alertDialog from outside of the function that made it?

If an alert is showing, then I want it to be dismissed if the app is closed and then resumed. However, I'm not sure how to get at the dialog from another listener (onResume).

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    ...

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        // ... show alert on error
        new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                .setMessage(alertMessage)
                .setTitle(alertTitle)
                .setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                .show();
    }

    public void onResume(){
         super.onResume();
         // Want to dismiss alert dialog here
     }

 }
```

Comment: what do you mean by app is closed and resumed?

Comment: The person goes to the homepage and then opens the app again. onResume is a standard listener for webview. However, the point is just that the dialog needs to be dismissed from an action that is not related to the user interacting with the dialog.

Comment: It could be better in onStop() of activity dismiss the dialog if it's showing. Better to assign dialog  to variable so that later you can dismiss.

Comment: Most things can be ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save AlertDialog in a private variable. So you can use it later and call dialog.dismiss().

```
private AlertDialog dialog;
```

And in your function onReceivedError:

```
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder.....
```

Comment: Ah, I see! show() is what returns the AlertDialog. I had been trying to set the dialog equal the builder and then calling show() later.

Answer (score 1):

declare AlertDialog object globally

```
private AlertDialog dialog;
```

**and user your code in function like this**

```
public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
    // ... show alert on error
   dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
            .setMessage(alertMessage)
            .setTitle(alertTitle)
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
            .show();}
```

and outside of your function you can dismiss it using the object of dialog box

```
dialog.dismiss();
```